# Do we like hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2014

***UPDATE*** We're in for the hats this year. We just submitted the form!

---

Last year, Stack Exchange ran [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), in which users earned hats which they proudly displayed upon their gravatar. There was a leaderboard of hatters, mad or not:

[image: 2013 top hat wearers]

It's that time of the year again and we get to choose whether we want to do it again this year. Hats are enabled on a per-site basis, but each site has to opt-in and choose to participate.

What are hats, I hear you ask. Well, hats are kinda like ephemeral badges. You can choose to have one displayed over your avatar and you win them by certain actions on the webpage. Users can turn off hats on a per-user basis, so if you're against them for any reason, you can disable the feature and not see your hats nor those of the users who have opted in. As far as you are concerned, the hats will not exist.

If we choose to accept, the event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. After that, all the hats go away into Last Year's Hat Bin.

We need to decide if we want hats by December 1. So, do we like hats or hate hats?

Comment: Meh, Community ♦ should be the one posting this D:

Comment: @Braiam that's _Mr._ Community♦ to you. :P

Comment: @terdon Sexist! Anyway it should be `community`, or `-1` with the `-n` option.

Comment: I'm resisting the urge to edit the question to say "your mission, should you choose to accept it," and link to the Mission: Impossible Wikipedia page, since that's what my mind _immediately_ went to when you said "if we choose to accept".

Comment: I thought a hat (like hair) was there to cover a non-perfect head. I guess not everyone can be so lucky to look like captain P.

Comment: @Anthon you remind me of a t-shirt my Dad used to have which carried the slogan "God made a few perfect heads. On the rest of them, he put hair". I may not agree with the theological implications there but I still find it funny.

Comment: @terdon That was exactly the quote I had in mind that was the basis for my comment, and I reworded it for exactly the same implications.

Comment: @Anthon Ah, all you people with wide [partings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parting?searchDictCode=all) think alike :)

Comment: Have the comment threads of [tag:Fedora] questions in previous hatsy years stayed in control?

Comment: @Anko oddly enough, yes. At least to my knowledge.

Comment: [status-completed] can now be added to this, since there will indeed be hats.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Yes, of course we want hats!

Don't be a hater, be a hatter!<sup>[1](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/192/90)</sup>

---

But I think the more important question is:

> [Why is a raven like a writing desk?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hatter#The_Hatter.27s_riddle)

Comment: Is there a Mad Hatter hat?

Comment: @Wilf I sure hope so!

Comment: HATS off to you sir :D

Comment: @Wilf There beret be one.

Answer (score -3):

## No to the hats!

Let the avatars be free, unencumbered by the headware of lollygaggers and poppinjays...

Comment: To the downvoter: really? How could we have a Yes/No poll with only one answer. Grinch.

Comment: Surely we need to downvote for this to be a yes/no poll!

Comment: @terdon Given this was a $holiday intiative, I foolishly assumed goodwill and a spirit of benevolence would apply; downvoting just seems as churlish as it is unecessary: vote for what you support, not to mark the counter proposal as "not useful".

Comment: Goodwill? Benevolence? But you're grinching! Seriously though, while I did not downvote, probably out of a spirit of goodwill and cheer and all that, it does seem reasonable to downvote. If only to offset the upvotes on the position you disagree with. As a general rule, these types of poll questions with directly contradicting answers need both upvotes and downvotes to make the community's position clear. After all, downvotes on meta can simply mean ["I disagree"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227015/203101), so I can understand the vote.

Comment: @terdon while an issue this trivial probably doesn't warrant extended discussion... Everyone only has one upvote (unless of course people both *want* and *don't want* hats); so the downvote is pointless--other than to magnify mean spiritedness, hence my Grinch comment.

Comment: They should implement this for regular ol' representational democracy.  I mostly don't vote (or else spoil my ballot, they have to count those), but I'd be in there every time if I could cast a negative vote for someone: "-1 for you jerk!"

Comment: I just really don't like people without hats ^

Comment: @goldilocks Nice suggestion, if this was implemented for public office then no one would get elected XD (Which is probably not that bad)

Comment: @datUser Someone still has to be elected, lol, but seeing them celebrate the least negative count would be great ("Only -7% support!"). I think there have been a few cases in U.S. municipal elections where the spoiled ballot won, not sure what happened after that.

Comment: @goldilocks Ah the true zero sum game. OK sorry for the off- topicness.