# how to disable this crazy hat thing?

Tags: support, winterbash-2014

I earned some kind of hat thing *(for what I don't know - who is Saint Lucia?)* and I dunno how to be rid of it. @terdon seems [to indicate](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3254/52934) I *can* turn it off... so how?

Comment: Posted without comment: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3257/6761

Comment: @jasonwryan - I guess it just goes to show you that you *SHOULD NEVER DISAGREE*

Comment: Maybe we need a Contrarian Hat?

Comment: @jasonwryan - hats are for suckers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the snowflake icon, and select "I hate hats", or go to your profile, and click the same (snowflake -> I hate hats).

On the other hand... YOU HAT HATTER :'(

Comment: i liked my tag better...